# Python, Boost C++ and Pyste

Tags: c++, python, boost-python

I'm using libboost_python and the Pyste generator to embed Python in my C++ lib.

I managed to generate a wrapper of one of my lib class. It compiles but I can't use it in Python because of the function signature which is different.

For example:

Pyste generate this C++ code for a MyLib::Object::Translate() method:

```
BOOST_PYTHON_MEMBER_FUNCTION_OVERLOADS(MyLib_Entity_Translate_overloads_3_4, Translate, 3, 4)

// Module ======================================================================                                                                                                 
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(mylib)
{
    scope* MyLib_Object_scope = new scope(
    class_< MyLib::Object, boost::noncopyable, MyLib_Object_Wrapper >("Object", init< const MyLib::String& >())
    .def("Translate", (void (MyLib::Entity::*)(const double&, const double&, const double&, const MyLib::Entity*) &MyLib::Entity::Translate, MyLib_Entity_Translate_overloads_3_4())
    /*...*/
    };
 }
```

and when I call it in Python with

```
this.Translate(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
```

I have this error

> Error in Python: : Python argument
>   types in
>       Object.Translate(Object, float, float, float) did not match C++ signature:
>       Translate(MyLib::Entity {lvalue}, double, double, double) :   File "testobj.py", line 2, in 
>       this.Translate(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)

Note that MyLib::Object inherited from MyLib::Entity

What should I do? Export MyLib::Entity too ? Convert all my C++ code from double to float ?

Comment: Hi! I use boost-python quite often and I'm very happy with it, but I never use Pyste... my hunch is that no automatic tool will entirely succeed in exposing C++ to Python.... so, are you sure you want to use Pyste?

Comment: no, I'm not sure. You right, it's a solution but I would like to use a wrap generator because there are more than 40 class in my project... (Maybe use both manual and generate wrapper)